# Kotlin: onGlobalLayout not being called

Tags: android, android-view, kotlin

I'm using Kotlin, and using onGlobalLayout to load an image view. through loadUrl. Without using afterMeasured, my image is loaded well, but at times due to the height is 0, it crashes. So I'm thinking using onGlobalLayout which I defined in my extension function afterMeasured as below. However somehow the onGlobalLayout never get called at all. What could be wrong with my code?

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ministry)
    actionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
    model = intent.getSerializableExtra(Constants.ACTIVITY_NAVIGATE_MINISTRY) as Model.Ministries
    actMinistryImage.loadUrl(model.photo)
}

fun ImageView.loadUrl(url: String?, placeholder: Int = R.drawable.ministries_blank) {
    this.afterMeasured {
        val transformation = FixRatioTransformation(this, true)
        Picasso.with(context).load(url).error(placeholder).transform(transformation)
                .placeholder(placeholder).into(this)
    }
}


inline fun <T: View> T.afterMeasured(crossinline f: T.() -> Unit) {
    viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
        override fun onGlobalLayout() {
            if (measuredWidth > 0 && measuredHeight > 0) {
                viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
                f()
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Perhaps this is not Kotlin specific, but more to invoking onGlobalLayout is not done correctly on my side?

Comment: how do you know `onGlobalLayout not being called`? because `f()` not being called?

Comment: Ya, the provided function is not called, and the picture is not loaded.

Comment: try to `Log.d` in the beginning of `onGlobalLayout` so that it is called everytime `onGlobalLayout` is called, not inside some conditional `if`

Comment: You're right, it was called but I guess my condition is not met. How do I ensure that my height and width are bigger than 0 and this get called again?

Comment: i have no idea what `measuredWidth` && `measuredHeight` are, and where they are set

Comment: measureHeight is from getMeasuredHeight and measureWidth is from getMeasuredWidth. In Kotlin, we could access the getter removing the get* keyword and different access it. It is essentially getMeasuredHeight() and getMeasureWidth(). The reason we use onGlobalLayout is to ensure the layout is done, and hence the width and height are now greater than 0. Is my assumption correct?

Comment: ok so you call getMeasureWidth() && getMeasuredHeight(), but on what View? BTW is it really easier to use kotlin instead of good old java?

Comment: That's on the ImageView. Using Kotlin so far so good. I have two apps working. Feel free to chat with me on if you like on Kotlin, would be nice to have someone to discuss with. Cheers.

Comment: i just heard about kotlin but never used it, is it just enough to install kotlin plugin in android studio to use it in the android development?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108733/discussion-between-elye-and-pskink).

Comment: Where is actMinistryImage being defined and assigned?

Comment: `actMinistryImage` is the id of the ImageView. Right after `setContentView(R.layout.activity_ministry)`, then it get instantiated. It's essentially similar to findViewById(R.id.actMinistryImage).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should compare `width` and `height` instead of `measuredWidth` and `measuredHeight`. The latter size is used only during the measure/layout process.

Second, you should make sure that `ImageView` is described properly in the layout. That is its `layout_width` and `layout_height` must not be `wrap_content`. Moreover, other views must not result in this `ImageView` has `0` size.

Comment: Thanks. Removing `measuredWidth > 0 && measuredHeight > 0)` works for me, and this is now working fine.